# How to trim last part of the string having delimiter?

Tags: bash

I have string(s) having delimiter underscore(_)

Input -

1. ABC_TEST
2. PQR_XYZ_TEST
3. PQR_XYZ_ABC_TEST

Expected output -

1. ABC
2. PQR_XYZ
3. PQR_XYZ_ABC

I want to remove only last part of the string. Can anyone suggest quicker way probably one-liner to achieve this?

Comment: Are the strings in a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string='ABC_TEST'
mod_string="${string%_*}"
echo "$mod_string"
ABC
```

Comment: parameter expansion is nice, here's a link to some other PE tricks: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion

Answer (score 1):

The basic sed command is:

```
sed 's/_TEST$//' filename
```

or, to remove anything after the last `_`:

```
sed 's/_[^_]*$//' filename
```

If the strings come from another command: `command | sed ...`

If it's a variable `sed ... <<< "${VARIABLE}"`

Comment: I have tried this already as TEST can be any word. so better to use parameter expansion method

Comment: @Rocky86 This has been fixed. See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716